# Uploading command-line utilities to PyPI

Tags: python, software-distribution, pypi

I made a program that should be run from the shell with only one command (like `$ program_name`, that's it). I'm confused if I should upload this program to the PyPI list because when I browse through the list I have only encountered packages/modules that are designed to be imported into other python programs.

The program is also specifically designed for python users, so only programmers who work with python would use it. It would be nice if I could upload it there mainly because it is easier to package and distribute and only python users would use it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can upload it.

There are plenty of command-line utilities listed on PyPI, including, for example, [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

In fact, there are over [2700 packages marked as running in the Console environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse&show=all&c=8).